# Disable Keyboard in Specific Chrome Tab/Window

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any method to completely disable the keyboard in a Chrome window or tab instance?

As I view lesson content on a second screen, I often intend to type on my primary display and mess up the position of my video forgetting to change the focus back and forth.  I'd like to use the mouse only on the second screen to protect this.

The lesson application has no settings to alter keyboard shortcuts.  I'd like turn off the keyboard completely in this Chrome tab or window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AutoHotKey to achive that:

simply put that in a .ahk file and run it with AutoHotkey

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 1


#if WinActive(" - Super User")
a::
b::
c::
...
```

You can replace " - Super User" with whatever your Chrome Tab says, to see the full Title you can hover over the Tab and in the Tooltip you can easily find a "rare" Part because all websites or other Windows with that Text containing in the Title is then blocked, you can disable the functionality of this Script using the TrayIcon to suspend all Hotkeys

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I will do this and report back.